# missing parameters and 400 error is coming in aws signature get api

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, laravel-5.8

I am trying to get signature from aws api in postman but getting MissingParameterThe request must contain the parameter Signature. In postman 400 bad request is coming in status.

Comment: Please add more detail of your question like what are you request parameter and what are your response and detail of error response or its screenshot. that will help you to get answer of your problem fast.

Comment: I am using aws route 53  and i need signature to pass in authorisation header.{"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."}

i have spent 2 days in this and now getting above error.

Comment: Check this [Link](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/t/the-request-signature-we-calculated-does-not-match-the-signature-you-provid/256395) out. It might help.